# Authenticate requests from a backend as well from the client in a service that uses OAuth flow based authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth

I've an API that uses OAuth authentication ([hydra](https://www.ory.sh/hydra/docs/)) to authenticated requests that are
coming from the user browser.
I would also like to send requests to the same API's also from another backend (NodeJS).
I'm a bit confused what is the best way to do it.

The current Authentication mechanism uses a refresh token (1h).

I was thinking about creating another client for the backend in hydra, but it seems strange that also the backend will use the same method with the refresh token like the browser (never saw this before).

Any help with how to address this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So... there are several concepts you might need to take into consideration here...

Since its conception the OAuth 2.0 family of standards distinguishes between [private (trusted) and public (potentially vulnerable to attacks) clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1). The client you've got running in the browser falls in the latter category, and thus most experienced OAuth devs out there would argue that it's not OK to use refresh tokens for this client. For you backend service (even if it is a simple backend-for-frontend) written in node, that's a completely different story - there it's OK to use and store refresh tokens.

If however your node.js backend is working "outside" an active customer session, i.e. tries to access customer data even when no customer is actively interacting with the frontend, you might also want to consider the machine-to-machine flow provided by OAuth 2.0 - the [Client Credentials Flow.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)